# Why does it appear that json4s JObject uses a List(Tuple2) under the hood

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

This is really bad if it is what I think it is. I'm still learning Scala so I could be missing something HUGE but if I need constant time access to a specific element in a JObject, wouldn't storing the elements as a List(Tuple2) be REALLY REALLY REALLY bad for runtime?

I'm working on an application which uses Spark... and it looks like Spark is using json4s. I could imagine there's a good reasoning behind this, or maybe I don't know enough about Scala yet to understand why this doesn't matter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Big-O isn't everything. In e.g. Javascript itself, property lookups are implemented using hash tables, which are nicely O(1)... except that for realistic-sized objects (e.g. 100 fields), a hash table tends to be around 100x slower than a simple linear search through a list. If you are using objects with millions of fields then yes, this would be bad for performance - but IMO that's bad object design; such things would be better expressed using data structures (arrays, maps etc.) rather than objects.

Comment: As a designer of a json "object" I would expect that an Object is represented by a map and an array is represented by a list or array native to the language in question. If a list was used rather than a map, I want to know the reason because I can't see the benefit of increasing the asymptotic runtime without a gain somewhere else. I'm running json transformations in Spark which will work over billions of records- each iteration through a list (even if it only contains 30 elements) to find a single or a couple of elements is going to cost quite a bit in overall runtime- so runtime is important

Comment: @user3120870 I wouldn't just assume that hash tables or trees will be faster than lists, even for ~30 elements, especially after you factor in the cost of creation, etc.

Comment: A `Vector` may have been the better option. But it's important to note that in JSON, sequence of the pairs within an object is significant, so the underlying data type needs to be sequential.

Comment: Slight correction, I don't believe the standards specify that object order is significant, but it also doesn't say that it isn't (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4). But I do believe that many libraries err on the side of exposing ordering.

Comment: Let me point out that until I encountered json4s, I have never seen a json library NOT use something associative like a hashmap or an associative array as it's implementation. Order of elements in json does not matter- therefore there needs to be no implied sequence.

Comment: We've taken something that could be n-time creation and constant-time access and turned it into order n-time creation and order n-time access in the worst case and nobody has really been able to justify why- except that in javascript associative arrays aren't as good as one might think. Json4s unfortunately does not appear to have a mailing list or I would ask them directly.

Comment: If you have a concrete example where this causes problems, you could open a ticket on https://github.com/json4s/json4s

Comment: Before I open a ticket, I more just have questions about why the design was done the way it was. For instance- a simple 

    'json \ "myitem" \ "mynesteditem"'

Seems like it should be a constant time operation- but what is really happening is that it's filtering the first underlying list in the JValue for the item that has "myitem" as a key and then filtering that resulting list for the item that has "mynesteditem" as a key. I'm doing this 100's of times in a single xform. What i've found is that I spend more time trying to play tricks to make it efficient rather than just doing it

Comment: "I wouldn't just assume that hash tables or trees will be faster than lists, even for ~30 elements, especially after you factor in the cost of creation, etc."

Umm. Please explain why. What you've provided is not an answer, and it provides no technical justification. For heavy access operations, how could you justify iterating a since list for fetching each element vs using a map. The same number of objects get created either way.

Comment: "Big-O isn't everything." Yes, it really is- and we've been using it for a very long time to explain the expected bounds of an algorithm. Replacing a constant time operation with a n-time operation is changing the bounds by orders of magnitude and without proper justification of the gains for this, I can't see how your answer is even valid. I'm not referring to javascript, I'm asking about Scala.

Comment: I reached out to one of the json4s developers. It appears this was an oversight and they are thinking about changing this. They don't have a mailing list so it seemed easier to ask on here in case this was a scala thing and I was missing something.